# How good is my pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

I am not sure if this is the place to post this. If it is not, forgive me. But I need your help.

I need to create some instructional videos and do not have the budget to hire a voice talent to dub it in english. Someone suggested I do it myself, but I am not sure about how good my pronunciation is.

I selected [this random text](http://www2.essex.ac.uk/iss/training/talif/htms/basic_formatting_using_word.htm) from the web and gave it a shot.

[Here is my voice saying the text](http://www.2shared.com/audio/ZsEOcCaa/audio.html). Forgive the speech flow, because I am seeing this text for the first time now. Focus on the pronunciation. How good is it on a scale from 0 to 10, being 10 the best?

Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: It is just a .wav file, no special software needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is for, but I could understand it well enough.

Comment: @Cerberus - how good in a scale from 0 to 10?

Comment: @DigitalRobot: Sorry, I have no idea how to grade pronunciation.

Comment: Almost certainly, if you are worried about it, it's not worth recording, except perhaps as a hobby. Certainly not to sell professionally. Instructors need to be both competent and confident to do instructional videos.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting "Off topic" close-votes. Pronunciation is explicitly on-topic, even if this is an unusual presentation of the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close not because it's off-topic but because it's subjective and vague.  However, StoneyB gives a great answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“How good is my pronunciation?” isn’t really the question you should be asking. What you want to know is “Is my pronunciation good enough for this production?”.

And that’s what in my shop (where we produce a lot of instructional videos) we call a “How big should a house be” question—meaning it can’t be meaningfully answered without a lot more background. Many more questions have to be answered first:

- Have you got editing software which will allow you to cut your audio
  in post into your video to synch up what’s heard with what’s seen, or
  will you have overlay on to the video track as it runs? Overlaying is
  very difficult for anyone who isn’t familiar with the process being
  described, which means you may be better served by doing it yourself,
  unless you develop a fairly detailed system of off-mic cues for the
  voicer. But be prepared to work through a dozen or so takes before
  you get it right. Is it worth your time?
- Who’s your audience? —your own pronunciation is probably adequate for
  a *native* speaker, who can extrapolate to Standard English on the
  fly,  but could be very difficult for a non-native speaker,
  particularly one whose native language is not yours. Similarly, an
  audience familiar with the concepts you’re discussing will find it
  easier to follow you than will an audience of complete n00bs.
- Where’s your script coming from? —the same considerations apply: a
  native speaker and an expert viewer can tolerate a lot more casual
  error than a non-native speaker or a novice.
- What level of production do you have in mind? — do you want something
  that looks and sounds fully “professional”, would you be satisfied
  with something quick-and-dirty that just sets forth the necessary
  information and illustrations, or do you want something in between?

And once all that is clear in your mind:

- What *is* your budget? —not enough for a professional “talent” could
  mean you haven’t got four or five hundred dollars to bring a pro
  voice into a pro studio, or it could mean you haven’t got fifty bucks
  to put a competent and hungry college student onto the same mic you
  used. Do you expect to make any money off of this project? — then you
  need to calculate how much the additional investment will enhance
  your product’s “sellability”.

I apologize if this is less helpful than you hoped. You might get useful guidance on some of the technical issues on  the [Audio-Visual Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) branch of SE.